# Error 1060 in PHP/MySQL web app update

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a web app I have installed on my server.
But when I'm following the steps from the programmer to update the app, it gives me that error :

```
An Error Occurred: Error Code: 1060 Error Text: Duplicate column name 'custom_1' Error Statement: ALTER TABLE `clients` ADD `custom_1` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL
```

Here's how the sql file that is trying to add these columns looks like :

```
ALTER TABLE  `clients` ADD  `custom_1` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE  `settings` ADD  `custom_1` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL AFTER  `company_email` ;

ALTER TABLE  `items` CHANGE  `quantity`  `quantity` DECIMAL( 9, 2 ) NOT NULL ;

ALTER TABLE  `quote_items` CHANGE  `quantity`  `quantity` DECIMAL( 9, 2 ) NOT NULL ;
```

What causes that type of error usually? What I read is that it's because a table already exists with that name (custom_1). But I tried changing the name of it, but still giving me the same error. Thanks!

I cannot give the URL, cause it's behind a login form that I cannot give public access.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're not creating a duplicate TABLE, you're creating a duplicate COLUMN within a table. `custom_1` already exists in the `clients` table.

Comment: Yea sorry I meant a column. So I need to change the "custom_1" column for something else? Weird thing is that most people using this script didn't had this error. Can it be something linked to my hosting provider?

Comment: your host is out-of-sync with what you expect it to have for a table structure. you'll have to figure out how/where that already-existing-now-causing-dupe-errors custom_1 field came from.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So re-installing the app will probably do the trick. Maybe I clicked something that already created that column, but now when the app is trying to get updated, it get stuck there cause that column is already there...